# How do I repair this laminate bubble?

Tags: kitchen-counters, laminate, countertops

I set a boiling hot pot on top of the laminate countertop & this happened:

[image]

Is there a way to repair that, or do I have to replace the countertop?

Comment: The only way I could see a repair going would be do use router to make a patch.

Comment: I'd go with a dark colored epoxy. Inject the right amount into the bubble, cover with a dispo piece of teflon, and a 50+ pound weight until it dries. Unless you're very skilled, or lucky, it's going to be ugly, but it won't be a bubble anymore.

Comment: What about the crack?  The laminate around the hole is also kinda brittle.  I'm looking at replacing the whole countertop, aren't I?

Comment: This depends on how much you need to keep the countertop.  You can fix it with new laminate but that is a lot of work and relatively a lot of money.  Might be best to glue it down temporarily and replace countertop.  If this section doesn't include a sink I would get rid of it for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are ways to repair this, but they aren't going to do you any aesthetic favors. In short, they'll be ugly, but functional repairs.

You don't have to replace the countertop if you're OK with the modified aesthetics.

Comment: Yeah that's the thing, I have to make it look nice because we're selling the house this year.